# How to add or combine multiple disable options or flags in Chrome shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome

Google removed some useful flags from their browser but they can still be activated using some keys/options in the Target: section of its shortcut. For example, you can use the following to hide the puzzle extension icon.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu`

And you can use this to hide the music icon when a video is playing.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=GlobalMediaControls`

I want to know how to use both of these at the same time. I tried the following but it only activated the last option.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu --disable-features=GlobalMediaControls`

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out. You have to use a comma to separate them like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu,GlobalMediaControls
```